# How can I install grub2 on Orange PI 3?

Tags: software-installation, grub2, boot-loader, arm, arm64

How can I install grub2 on orange pi3 ?

Due to undisclosed reasons I can't connect my board to internet.

Therefore, I can not use `apt-get` or anything like that to install the grub2

In [What’s Orange Pi 3?](http://www.orangepi.org/Orange%20Pi%203/) there is some hardware Specification of Orange PI 3.

Comment: Are you sure grub2 is even available for that hardware? I know that grub is not available for some arm systems - they often use different bootloaders (e.g. u-boot).

Comment: @Time4Tea  the orange pi3 processor is allwinner h6 (Cortex -A53) . this chip architecture is ARMv8-A that has backward compatibility with ARMv7 and grub2 supports ARMv7 therefor, grub2 is compatible with orange pi3 hardware